# Pasquill-Gifford stability class data for one station

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling

On my project, *Stability classes* is an useful tool to analysis the weather condition for one place.

Using R Package `Worldmet`, I can get the hourly weather data for specific weather station based on its code at NOAA-NCDC in the world.

It contain variable like this:

- **"ws", "wd"**： wind direction and speed
- **"air_temp", "atmos_pres",  "visibility", "dew_point", "RH"**: these variables' meaning is obvious.
- **"ceil_hgt"**： ceiling height
- **"cl_1", "cl_2", "cl_3", "cl"**: Cloud cover for different layers in Oktas (1-8)
- **"cl_1_height", "cl_2_height", "cl_3_height"**: Height of the cloud base for each later in metres.
- **"pwc"**: The description of the present weather description (if available)

I want to classify the stability classes hourly based on those variables.

Referencing to the chart follows which I clipped from [NOAA](https://www.ready.noaa.gov/READYpgclass.php)
http://7xrn7f.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/16-3-10/83493087.jpg

I found out my variables may not support the classify job.

Is there some better computation way or data access to get the stability classes for one site?